# Do we have to provide images for all the logos for a windows phone 8.1 app in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I am new to developing windows phone apps. In Package.appxmanifest, under Visual Assets, there is a section "Tile Images and Logos":

```
Square 71x71 Logo
Square 150x150 Logo
Wide 310x150 Logo
Square 44x44 Logo
```

And for each of those, there are different "scales" 140, 100 etc. Do I need to provide an image for each of them, or is it sufficient to provide just the largest one ? For example, for Square 71x71 Logo, I have just provided the 170x170 px image.

Answer (score 1):

If you use this official resource by Microsoft, you need only provide the largest image and the system will scale down the rest. Give it a try -

http://www.buildmypinnedsite.com/en

Comment: Go to that link I provided. Expand step 1. Upload an image. Continue to steps 2 and 3. Download your resources. Use them in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Having only one of them should suffice, but I would advise you to add a logo for each size for the following reasons:

1. Even if you add the largest image only and it scales it down automatically, you'd be essentially using extra memory space which can be avoided.
2. You may not notice it on the emulator, but your logo would differ a lot from one screen to another should you choose to upload only one (not the largest). Some screens are much bigger (longer/wider) than others, and that's why they ask for many logos.

It would take little effort to adjust sizes and dimensions of the same logo to fit every required one, so I would really recommend it.

Good day!

Edit: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230259.aspx  (scroll down to visual assets and read) :)